# Oracle SQL - Using Function to get Average of values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use a Method to get the average of a score within a table.
I thought it would be simple but obviously not..
It's currently the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Team_Type AS OBJECT
(TeamReviewed REF Game_Type,
Team VARCHAR2(30),
TeamScore NUMBER(1),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating RETURN NUMBER)
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Team_Type
AS
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
  RETURN NUMBER
IS 
avg_score NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT AVG(TeamScore)
INTO avg_score FROM DUAL; 
RETURN avg_score;
END;
END;
/
CREATE TABLE Team_Table of Team_Type
/
INSERT INTO Team_Table 
VALUES((SELECT REF(a) FROM Game_Table a WHERE a.gameid = 1000000), 'Team A', 2)
/
INSERT INTO Team_Table
VALUES((SELECT REF(a) FROM Game_Table a WHERE a.gameid = 1000000), 'Team B', 6)
```

I can get the average using

```
select avg(teamscore)
from team_table
where teamreviewed = (select ref(a) from game_table a where a.gameid=1000000)
```

But the below just returns the score (in this case 2 and 6) rather than averaging it out.

```
SELECT p.team_rating() from team_table p where p.teamreviewed = (select 
ref(a) from game_table a where a.gameid=1000000)
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: AVG is an aggregate function that evaluates the average of an expression over a set of rows not on sigle rows. In your object when you use AVG it consider only that row and returns the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object is represents a single row in the table.

The member function:

```
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating RETURN NUMBER
IS 
  avg_score NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(TeamScore)
  INTO avg_score FROM DUAL; 
  RETURN avg_score;
END;
```

Uses the `DUAL` table - which has a single row and takes the average of the Object's `TeamScore` attribute - which is a single value - so your function could just be rewritten as:

```
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating RETURN NUMBER
IS 
  avg_score NUMBER;
BEGIN
  RETURN TeamScore;
END;
```

It is unclear what you want to average but something like:

```
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating RETURN NUMBER
IS 
  avg_score NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(TeamScore)
  INTO   avg_score
  FROM   Team_Table t
  WHERE  t.team = self.team;

  RETURN avg_score;
END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf973e/1)

**Query 1**:

```
select avg(teamscore)
from team_table
where teamreviewed = (select ref(a) from game_table a where a.gameid=1000000)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf973e/1/0)**:

```
| AVG(TEAMSCORE) |
|----------------|
|              4 |
```

Comment: OP already posted the way you are trying to show to get the AVG. What he asking is why is he not getting AVG using second way which is ideally not possible until he has all the table rows avaible in the Object body,

Comment: @XING If you read what I have posted in the text between the snippets -
 the first snippet is the OP's code, the second snippet is the simplified equivalent of the OP's (non-working) code and the third snippet is what the OP wants (with a link to a working SQLFIDDLE). You appear to have entirely missed the point with your comment.