# Method Function not getting values from single row (Nested table)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I've asked a question [related to this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642346/oracle-sql-using-function-to-get-average-of-values) but have a second question. I commented that I made a nested table of the teams that played rather than separate rows for each team and score.

I want to run the Method for a particular GameId rather than all the rows in the table.. I've included my Game_Type Object this time though I didn't think it was necessary last time.

```
CREATE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT
(GameId NUMBER)
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table 
VALUES (1)
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES (2)
/
CREATE TYPE Team_Type AS OBJECT
(TeamPlayed VARCHAR2(30),
TeamScore NUMBER(1))
/

CREATE TYPE TeamsPlayed_Table as TABLE OF Team_Type
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE After_Team AS OBJECT
(GameRef REF Game_Type,
GamePlayed Teamsplayed_Table,
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating RETURN NUMBER)
/
CREATE TABLE Team_Table of After_Team NESTED TABLE GamePlayed STORE AS 
GamePlayed_Nested
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY After_Team
AS
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
  RETURN NUMBER
IS 
avg_score NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT AVG(c.TeamScore)
INTO avg_score
FROM Team_Table d, table(d.GamePlayed) c;
RETURN avg_score;
END;
END;
/

INSERT INTO Team_Table 
VALUES((SELECT REF(a) FROM Game_Table a WHERE a.gameid = 1), 
(TeamsPlayed_Table(Team_Type('Team A', 1), Team_Type('Team B', 3))))
/

INSERT INTO Team_Table 
VALUES((SELECT REF(a) FROM Game_Table a WHERE a.gameid = 2), 
(TeamsPlayed_Table(Team_Type('Team C', 5), Team_Type('Team D', 9))))
/
```

Now when I execute my method:

```
SELECT t.team_rating()
from Team_Table t
where t.GameRef.GameId = 1
```

It's returning the average for all the values as opposed to just Game 1..

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642516/1509264) to your initial question - you need a `WHERE` clause in the `team_rating` function. Something I've already said was missing from the answer you accepted.

Comment: Have given you credit for the answer on other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the average of the `TeamScore` in the `GamePlayed` collection for that team then you can do it in pure PL/SQL (without a context-switch into the SQL scope):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY After_Team
AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS 
    avg_score NUMBER := 0;
    j INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. self.GamePlayed.COUNT LOOP
      IF self.GamePlayed(i) IS NOT NULL AND self.GamePlayed(i).TeamScore IS NOT NULL THEN
        avg_score := avg_score + self.GamePlayed(i).TeamScore;
        j := j + 1;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF j > 0 THEN
      RETURN avg_score / j;
    ELSE
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
  END;
END;
/
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9772d/1)

otherwise, you could use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY After_Team
AS
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION team_rating
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS 
    avg_score NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    SELECT avg( TeamScore )
    INTO   avg_score
    FROM   TABLE( self.GamePlayed );

    RETURN avg_score;
  END;
END;
/
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fc96b/1)